# How to dynamically allocate cells in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dynamic, qtablewidget

Im a student programmer and Im using Qt to build a GUI for one of my company's product. Essentially this GUI is going to read certain files and feed the data into a table for users to edit. I know how to construct the QTableWidget statically. In which case i used the following:

```
 for(int x=0; x < ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->rowCount(); x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->columnCount(); y++)
        {
            ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(x,y, qTableWidgetItemInjection);
        }
    }
```

The problem is this way creates a static or fixed number of cells I would instead like the cells to be constructed based on the user interaction. Perhaps when a user fills any cells in the last line to populate a new one or when the user scrolls down... I digress the thing is I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to approach this in [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html). Maybe its writers block or I'm missing something obvious but any help would be awesome. Thanks for reading and thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a row, just do a `QAbstractItemModel::insertRow`on your `QTableWidget::model()`.
The `QTableWidget` will adjust itself automatically.

i.e.

```
ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->model()->insertRow(ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->model()->rowCount());
```

to add a row after the last one.

There are tons of way to trigger the append, you'd have to be more precise on what you want...

Comment: I think that's actually a good start; in such case I think Id like to use the down scroll to append additional rows. I cant seem to find a signal handler for this in the Qt documentation; got any direction for this?

Comment: Down scroll? You mean clicking on the down arrow on the scrollbar when on the last line? Besides the fact that I'm not sure it is doable, what would happen if there are no scroll bars because all the rows fit the viewport?

Comment: Well like most spreadsheet applications I will have to start out with a fixed amount of rows to ensure that there are enough to ensure a scroll bar. I suppose a button could be implemented to add rows on the fly but that kinda takes away that dynamic ability. I suppose performance will have to be considered here as I a check data function will be ran as cells are modified. As you said "not sure its doable".